# Simplificar código que debe ser repetido con varias variables

Tags: php

He creado un switch con varios cases que según el valor me de un texto lo que sucede que debo hacerlo con múltiples campos y sería repetir el código que es algo extenso o ver de que forma simplificarlo que debe haber alguna.

```
switch ($s1) {
    case (($s1 >= 0) && ($s1 < 10)): $im1 = "Indefinido"; break; 
    case (($s1 >= 10) && ($s1 <= 20)): $im1 = "Definiendo";break; 
    case ($s1 > 20): $im1 = "Definido"; break;
}
```

El `$s1` va relacionado a este código que obtiene todos los campos y los suma.

```
$s1=$s2=$s3=$s4= 0; 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
    $s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor1"];
```

Y así con cada linea la cuestión es que obtiene todo el valor de los campos en `$Datos[$i]["Valor1"];` y después uso `$s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor1"];` para así llamarlo en el `switch $s1` pero debo repetir el paso con `$s2`, `$s3`, `$s4` y me preguntaba si me podéis  echar un cable a simplificarlo.

**Edición:**

La linea que repito es:

El $s1 es $s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor1"];

```
switch ($s1) {
    case (($s1 >= 0) && ($s1 < 10)): $im1 = "Indefinido"; break; 
    case (($s1 >= 10) && ($s1 <= 20)): $im1 = "Definiendo";break; 
    case ($s1 > 20): $im1 = "Definido"; break;
}
```

a

El $s2 es $s2 += $Datos[$i]["Valor2"];

```
switch ($s2) {
    case (($s2 >= 0) && ($s2 < 10)): $im2 = "Indefinido"; break; 
    case (($s2 >= 10) && ($s2 <= 20)): $im2 = "Definiendo";break; 
    case ($s2 > 20): $im2 = "Definido"; break;
}
```

En vez de crear tanta linea.

**Código funcional**

$Datos es obtenido de la base datos por eso extraigo la información en $Datos[$i][CELDA]

```
$s1=$s2=$s3=$s4=$s5=$s6=$s7=$s8= 0; for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
$s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor1"];$s2 += $Datos[$i]["Valor2"];
$s3 += $Datos[$i]["Valor3"];$s4 += $Datos[$i]["Valor4"];

$s5 += $Datos[$i]["Valor5"];$s6 += $Datos[$i]["Valor6"];
$s7 += $Datos[$i]["Valor7"];$s8 += $Datos[$i]["Valor8"];}

switch ($s1) {case (($s1 > 0) && ($s1 < 10)): $im1 = "Valor1 10"; break; case (($s1 >= 10) && ($s1 <= 20)): $im1 = "Valor1 20";break; case ($s1 > 20): $im1 = "Valor1 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s2) {case (($s2 > 0) && ($s2 < 10)): $im2 = "Valor2 10"; break; case (($s2 >= 10) && ($s2 <= 20)): $im2 = "Valor2 20";break; case ($s2 > 20): $im2 = "Valor2 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s3) {case (($s3 > 0) && ($s3 < 10)): $im3 = "Valor3 10"; break; case (($s3 >= 10) && ($s3 <= 20)): $im3 = "Valor3 20";break; case ($s3 > 20): $im3 = "Valor3 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s4) {case (($s4 > 0) && ($s4 < 10)): $im4 = "Valor4 10"; break; case (($s4 >= 10) && ($s4 <= 20)): $im4 = "Valor4 20";break; case ($s4 > 20): $im4 = "Valor4 > 20"; break;}

switch ($s5) {case (($s5 > 0) && ($s5 < 10)): $im5 = "Valor5 10"; break; case (($s5 >= 10) && ($s5 <= 20)): $im5 = "Valor5 20";break; case ($s5 > 20): $im5 = "Valor5 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s6) {case (($s6 > 0) && ($s6 < 10)): $im6 = "Valor6 10"; break; case (($s6 >= 10) && ($s6 <= 20)): $im6 = "Valor6 20";break; case ($s6 > 20): $im6 = "Valor6 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s7) {case (($s7 > 0) && ($s7 < 10)): $im7 = "Valor7 10"; break; case (($s7 >= 10) && ($s7 <= 20)): $im7 = "Valor7 20";break; case ($s7 > 20): $im7 = "Valor7 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s8) {case (($s8 > 0) && ($s8 < 10)): $im8 = "Valor8 10"; break; case (($s8 >= 10) && ($s8 <= 20)): $im8 = "Valor8 20";break; case ($s8 > 20): $im8 = "Valor8 > 20"; break;}
```

Y con ese código se me queda la variable echo $im8; entre otras para un uso especifico ese es el resultado funcional que tengo pero sin optimizar como se puede apreciar.

Comment: Hola Vicente, te recomendaría añadir un default, ya que si $s1 es menor que 0, no entraría en ninguno de los cases

Comment: ¿Por qué no creas una función con el código común y luego la llamas para cada variable?

Comment: rencinas el valor no será nunca menor a 0 pero gracias por el detalle.

@AlvaroMontoro cómo podría hacerlo ya que lo que quiero es no tener que copiar tanto código y si con eso lo simplifica.

Comment: El `switch` es la parte que se repite para cada variable, ¿no? Entonces podrías moverlo a una función que devuelva el valor de `$im` y llamar a esa función para cada una de las variables `$s` que tengas (en un bucle o como prefieras). Básicamente es lo que te sugiere Carmen.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ahí edite me había saltado una paso crucial  ya que el valor va cambiando a Valor1,  Valor2 por eso cambia el $s1, $s2 al igual $im1 y $im2 y intento evitar crear múltiples párrafos solo cambiando esos valores.

Comment: @Vicente en lugar de poner snippets pequeños con información parcial, ¿por qué no pones directamente el código que tienes y que quieres simplificar? Va a ser más fácil verlo en su totalidad que por partes o sólo una parte y suponer que el resto es igual. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve].

Comment: También, y como sugerencia aparte, quizás podrías plantearte usar arrays en lugar de variables enumeradas (p.e. en lugar de tener `$im1`, `$im2`... `$imN` podrías tener un array `$im` de N posiciones, y lo mismo para `$s`)

Comment: Si lo había pensado el problema era principalmente la linea principal el otro fue una amera de ponerlo a funcionar por eso quiero ir simplificando ahí edito y pongo el código funcional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes crear una función que ejecute el código común, en este caso el bucle, y te devuelva el resultado, de modo que sólo tienes que pasarle el valor cómo parámetro cuando la llamas. Por ejemplo:

```
function estado($number) {
  if ($number>=20) {$txt = "Definido";}
  else if ($number>=10) {$txt = "Definiendo";}
  else if ($number>=0) {$txt = "Indefinido";}
  else {$txt="OutOfLimit";}
  return $txt;
}

$Datos[0]["Valor"]=2;
$Datos[1]["Valor"]=20;

$s1=0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
    $s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor"];
    echo estado($s1)."<br>";
}
```

Resultado:

```
Indefinido
Definido
```

**Edición tras aclaraciones de la pregunta:** para distintas variable sirve igualmente porque a la función le pasamos el valor numérico que corresponde en cada caso y extraemos el resultado.

```
function estado($number) {
      if ($number>20) {$txt = "Definido";} //>20
      else if ($number>=10) {$txt = "Definiendo";} //de 10 a 20 
      else if ($number>=0) {$txt = "Indefinido";} //de 0 a 9
      else {$txt="OutOfLimit";} //otro valor(negativos)
      return $txt;
    }

    $Datos[0]["Valor1"]=2;
    $Datos[1]["Valor1"]=20;

    $Datos[0]["Valor2"]=10;
    $Datos[1]["Valor2"]=22;

    $Datos[0]["Valor3"]=5;
    $Datos[1]["Valor3"]=25;

    $s1=0; $s2=0; $s3=0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
        $s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor1"];
        $s2 += $Datos[$i]["Valor2"];
        $s3 += $Datos[$i]["Valor3"];
        //Aquí le das valor a todas las variables. Y luego ejecutas la función para cada variable
        echo estado($s1)."<br>".estado($s2)."<br>".estado($s3)."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: La cuestión es reducir el código ya que no solo debo usar $s1, usare $s2, $s3 y más y la intención es no ir copiando la linea.

switch ($s1) {
    case (($s1 >= 0) && ($s1 < 10)): $im1 = "Indefinido"; break; 
    case (($s1 >= 10) && ($s1 <= 20)): $im1 = "Definiendo";break; 
    case ($s1 > 20): $im1 = "Definido"; break;
}

switch ($s2) {
    case (($s2 >= 0) && ($s2 < 10)): $im2 = "Indefinido"; break; 
    case (($s2 >= 10) && ($s2 <= 20)): $im2 = "Definiendo";break; 
    case ($s2 > 20): $im2 = "Definido"; break;
}

Comment: @Vicente ese código parece más completo que el de la pregunta, quizás sería bueno que editaras la pregunta para ponerlo y que se vea mejor el problema que estás planteando

Comment: Es el mismo código pero como comente duplico las lineas ya que no es solo para un valor.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro teniaz razón me había saltado código por mencionar ahí os edite .

Comment: @carmen me había saltado código espero que puedan interpretarlo mejor ahora.

Comment: @Vicente sólo tienes que llamar a la misma función para la variable $s2 después de asignarle el valor con echo estado($s2); al ser el.mismo bucle es válido para cualquier valor que le pases. La única corrección tras tu edición sería cambiar >= por > en el primer if.

Comment: @Carmen hay he puesto el código funcional y la finalidad el problema del código que me mencionas es que solo es usado por [Valor] no por [Valor1], [Valor2] ect...

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
    $s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor"];
    echo estado($s1)."<br>";
}

Comment: @Vicente edito la respuesta para aclarartelo

Comment: @Carmen Vale gracias.

Comment: @Carmen lo me estaba liando eran los valores que estabas usando para hacerlo funcionar, finalmente solo con la función tuya de estado lo hice andar ahorrando mucho código.

Comment: @Vicente de eso se trata, me alegra que te haya servido

Comment: Si justo tu parte del código al que tenia haciendo array a la db fusionado queda de 10 ahora estoy intentado optimizarlo con el del amigo alvaro que se ve con potencial aunque no me l interpreta y estará listo.

Comment: @Carmen podrías darle si tienes tiempo a este código haber si tu ves error  for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
  for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
     $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor" . ($j+1)];
  }
}

Comment: @Vicente lo he probado y me funciona bien, antes del for he definido $s = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); y luego he probado for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { or ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) { $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor".($j+1)]; echo estado($s[$j])."<br>"; } }

Comment: @Carmen Ya he visto donde está el error a simple vista el código esta bien pero el problema estaba en $s[$j] que en teoria iba a hacer $s1, $s2 y comiendo la cabeza el resultado que me daba era siempre 0 y es porque en vez de ser $s1 es $s[1]; hay forma de que sea $s1... si no al menos ya funciona...      $s = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); 
     
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
        for ($j = 1; $j < 8; $j++) { 
            $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor".($j)]; } } 
            var_dump($Datos[0]["Valor1"]);
            var_dump($s[1]);

Comment: @Vicente es mejor declararlo y rellenarlo como array para hacer el proceso de forma sencilla y efectiva dentro de los bucles, de este modo sólo tienes que llamar por la posición.

Comment: @Carmen Es decir que es mejor así yo lo estaba mirando más aspecto visual pero si así es más limpio.

Comment: Si, asi queda limpio y claro

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un par de juegos de 8 variables (`$s` y `$im`) todas enumeradas del 1 al 8, en lugar de tener esas 16 variables, podrías tener dos arrays de tamaño 8 cada uno y acceder con un iterador/índice.

Vamos a ir por partes. Esto:

```
$s1=$s2=$s3=$s4=$s5=$s6=$s7=$s8= 0;
```

se puede cambiar por el array mencionado arriba:

```
$s = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Luego esta parte también se podría simplificar si la pones dentro de un bucle que se repita una vez por cada elemento del array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 

    $s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor1"];$s2 += $Datos[$i]["Valor2"];
    $s3 += $Datos[$i]["Valor3"];$s4 += $Datos[$i]["Valor4"];

    $s5 += $Datos[$i]["Valor5"];$s6 += $Datos[$i]["Valor6"];
    $s7 += $Datos[$i]["Valor7"];$s8 += $Datos[$i]["Valor8"];
}
```

Algo como esto:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
  for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
     $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor" . ($j+1)];
  }
}
```

Y finalmente puedes hacer algo parecido también para todos los `switch`:

```
switch ($s1) {case (($s1 > 0) && ($s1 < 10)): $im1 = "Valor1 10"; break; case (($s1 >= 10) && ($s1 <= 20)): $im1 = "Valor1 20";break; case ($s1 > 20): $im1 = "Valor1 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s2) {case (($s2 > 0) && ($s2 < 10)): $im2 = "Valor2 10"; break; case (($s2 >= 10) && ($s2 <= 20)): $im2 = "Valor2 20";break; case ($s2 > 20): $im2 = "Valor2 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s3) {case (($s3 > 0) && ($s3 < 10)): $im3 = "Valor3 10"; break; case (($s3 >= 10) && ($s3 <= 20)): $im3 = "Valor3 20";break; case ($s3 > 20): $im3 = "Valor3 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s4) {case (($s4 > 0) && ($s4 < 10)): $im4 = "Valor4 10"; break; case (($s4 >= 10) && ($s4 <= 20)): $im4 = "Valor4 20";break; case ($s4 > 20): $im4 = "Valor4 > 20"; break;}

switch ($s5) {case (($s5 > 0) && ($s5 < 10)): $im5 = "Valor5 10"; break; case (($s5 >= 10) && ($s5 <= 20)): $im5 = "Valor5 20";break; case ($s5 > 20): $im5 = "Valor5 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s6) {case (($s6 > 0) && ($s6 < 10)): $im6 = "Valor6 10"; break; case (($s6 >= 10) && ($s6 <= 20)): $im6 = "Valor6 20";break; case ($s6 > 20): $im6 = "Valor6 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s7) {case (($s7 > 0) && ($s7 < 10)): $im7 = "Valor7 10"; break; case (($s7 >= 10) && ($s7 <= 20)): $im7 = "Valor7 20";break; case ($s7 > 20): $im7 = "Valor7 > 20"; break;}
switch ($s8) {case (($s8 > 0) && ($s8 < 10)): $im8 = "Valor8 10"; break; case (($s8 >= 10) && ($s8 <= 20)): $im8 = "Valor8 20";break; case ($s8 > 20): $im8 = "Valor8 > 20"; break;}
```

Para los que puedes crear otro bucle que atraviese el array y vaya asignando valores:

```
$im = ["","","","","","","",""];

for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
  switch ($s[$j]) {
    case (($s[$j] > 0) && ($s[$j] < 10)): $im[$j] = "Valor" . ($j+1) . " 10"; break; 
    case (($s[$j] >= 10) && ($s[$j] <= 20)): $im[$j] = "Valor" . ($j+1) . " 20";break; 
    case ($s[$j] > 20): $im[$j] = "Valor" . ($j+1) . " > 20"; break;}
}
```

---

Y todo junto se vería así:

```
$s = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
$im = ["","","","","","","",""];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
  for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
     $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor" . ($j+1)];
  }
}   

for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
  switch ($s[$j]) {
    case (($s[$j] > 0) && ($s[$j] < 10)): $im[$j] = "Valor" . ($j+1) . " 10"; break; 
    case (($s[$j] >= 10) && ($s[$j] <= 20)): $im[$j] = "Valor" . ($j+1) . " 20";break; 
    case ($s[$j] > 20): $im[$j] = "Valor" . ($j+1) . " > 20"; break;
  }
}
```

Con ese código he hecho una prueba usando el siguiente set de `$Datos`:

```
$Datos = [
    [ "Valor1" => 1, "Valor2" => 2, "Valor3" => 3, "Valor4" => 4, "Valor5" => 5, "Valor6" => 6, "Valor7" => 7, "Valor8" => 8 ],
    [ "Valor1" => 1, "Valor2" => 2, "Valor3" => 3, "Valor4" => 4, "Valor5" => 5, "Valor6" => 6, "Valor7" => 7, "Valor8" => 8 ],
    [ "Valor1" => 1, "Valor2" => 2, "Valor3" => 3, "Valor4" => 4, "Valor5" => 5, "Valor6" => 6, "Valor7" => 7, "Valor8" => 8 ],
    [ "Valor1" => 1, "Valor2" => 2, "Valor3" => 3, "Valor4" => 4, "Valor5" => 5, "Valor6" => 6, "Valor7" => 7, "Valor8" => 8 ],
    [ "Valor1" => 1, "Valor2" => 2, "Valor3" => 3, "Valor4" => 4, "Valor5" => 5, "Valor6" => 6, "Valor7" => 7, "Valor8" => 8 ]
];
```

Y haciendo `var_dump` de `$s` e `$im` obtengo respectivamente:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  int(5)
  [1]=>
  int(10)
  [2]=>
  int(15)
  [3]=>
  int(20)
  [4]=>
  int(25)
  [5]=>
  int(30)
  [6]=>
  int(35)
  [7]=>
  int(40)
}

array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Valor1 10"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Valor2 20"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "Valor3 20"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "Valor4 20"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "Valor5 > 20"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "Valor6 > 20"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "Valor7 > 20"
  [7]=>
  string(11) "Valor8 > 20"
}
```

Comment: Me ha servido tu código junto al de Carmen que me hace reducir bastante código pero tengo un problema  he querido utilizar de tu código para remplazar el actual

    $s = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
    $s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor1"];$s2 += $Datos[$i]["Valor2"];
    $s3 += $Datos[$i]["Valor3"]; 
... más código.

Pero  no funciona y tampoco veo el error en tu código se ve bastante funcional...

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
      for ($j = 1; $j < 9; $j++) {
         $s[$i] += $Datos[$i]["Valor" . $j];
      }
    }

Comment: @Vicente Me acabo de dar cuenta de que hay un fallo. Porque podría excederse el tamaño del array porque estoy usando el índice incorrecto. He corregido estas líneas: `for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
         $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor" . ($j+1)];` Revisa el código de nuevo.

Comment: @Vicente después de corregir eso, he realizado un par de pruebas y funciona sin problemas (o al menos eso parece).

Comment: Pues por más que intento me esta dando valor de 0 y en el normal me carga los valores sin problema.

Comment: ¿Cómo los cargas? Añade eso también a la pregunta. Por favor lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve].

Comment: Lo cargo con while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ $Datos[]=$row; }  Según veo por las pruebas que hago que lo que no interpreta es $s[$j] += $Datos[0] no interpreta la [$j] ya que si pongo el número directamente me lo visualiza correctamente.

Comment: @Vicente Cambiaste los índices de `$j` para que vayan de 0 a 8 en lugar de de 1 a 9?

Comment: Si lo cambie hasta estuve probando de ponerlo de otra manera pero se ve que [$j] no quiere leerlo de esa manera.

Comment: No se porque motivo no me deja ponerlo  he probado cambiándolo de orden y tampoco.

Comment: has encontrado el error? aún no lo encuentro.

Comment: @Vicente la cosa es que a mí no me da error, como pongo en la respuesta. Reduciendo el código así, me funciona bien. ¿Qué versión de PHP estás usando? ¿Cuál es tu código completo (mínimo para reproducir el problema)?

Comment: acabo de dar con el problema pensaba que la finalidad del código iba a ser $s1, $s2 como lo tenia en mi código y que estaba el $j metido en corchetes estuve haciendo pruebas y es de la unica forma que corra entonces yo estaba cargando $s1 y me daba siempre 0 por eso no había error pero la carga correcta era $s[1]; hay forma de pasarlo a $s1, $s2 si no al menos la función como tal me sirve. $s = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { for ($j = 1; $j < 8; $j++) { $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor".($j)]; } } var_dump($Datos[0]["Valor1"]); var_dump($s[1]);

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres hacerlo de esa manera puedes utilizar variables variables
http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php
Saludos!